# How to change UILabel value in CustomAnnotation by clicking button in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, mkmapview

I have added a custom annotation and a percentage label on it.
[image]

By pressing the button in red circle, I want to change value of label from percentage to business name.

My Code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[BusinessCustomAnnotation class]]) {

        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *) [mapViewOffers dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];

            UILabel* category = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(annotationView.frame.size.width / 2, 15, 55, 20)];

            BusinessCustomAnnotation *myAnnotationView = (BusinessCustomAnnotation *)annotation;

            NSLog(@"Type One Offer! = %i", mapTypes);
            [category setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];

            if (mapTypes == 1) {
                category.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", myAnnotationView.offerPercentage, @"%"];
            }else if (mapTypes == 2){
                category.text = myAnnotationView.businessName;
            }else if (mapTypes == 3){
                category.text = myAnnotationView.businessName;
            }

            [category setMinimumScaleFactor:1.0];
            category.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0 weight:5.0];
            category.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            [annotationView addSubview:category];

            annotationView.enabled = YES;
            annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
            annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iconMapMarker"];//here we use a nice image instead of the default pins
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        return annotationView; }return nil; }
```

Above mapview delegate is calling for one time only.
Waiting for the solution.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of detecting user interaction with your annotation view. The common technique is to define a callout (that standard little popover bubble that you see when you tap on a pin in a typical maps app) for your MKAnnotationView. And you create the annotation view for your annotation in the standard viewForAnnotation method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"loc"];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    return annotationView;
}
```

By doing this, you get a callout, but you're adding an right accessory, which is, in my example above, a disclosure indicator. That way, they tap on your annotation view (in my example above, a pin on the map), they see the callout, and when they tap on that callout's right accessory (the little disclosure indicator in this example), your calloutAccessoryControlTapped is called.

```
   - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
    {
         //first check your view class here 
       // here your code for change text on view
    }

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    //first check your view class here 
  // here your code for change text on view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the annotations. In Action of button try this :

```
  mapTypes = 2

    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations)
    {
        [mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
        [mapView addAnnotation:annotation]; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make any changes to already added annotation pin.To make any changes to the annotation pin you need to remove all the pin and add it back.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations don't refresh.

You have to remove all existing annotations with

[self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];

and update your "mapTypes" variable value to "2" or "3" in order to show business name.

Then you can can add your annotations again with [MKMapView addAnnotation:].